# R - count maximum number of consecutive dates

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tibble

I'm trying to count the maximum length of consecutive dates by group, but I'm struggling to get it. I have included code for a similarly laid-out tibble to mine.

```
library(dplyr)

# construct sample tibble:
df <- tibble(
  key = rep(1:2, c(6,4)),
  Date = c(seq(as.Date('2016-12-17'), as.Date('2016-12-19'), '1 day'),
           seq(as.Date('2016-12-21'), as.Date('2016-12-23'), '1 day'),
           seq(as.Date('2017-05-18'), as.Date('2017-05-21'), '1 day'))          
)
```

I tried to use `lag()` to add a tag (`1`) to indicate when there was a gap between dates, and then count the max length of `0` in the column using `rle`, but this doesn't work for all possible configurations of consecutive dates and gaps within `keys`.

Is there a way to return the maximum number of consecutive dates by group?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's first make a function that would find the maximum number of consecutive days, given a vector:

```
gl <- function(x) {
  y <- c(unclass(diff(x)))  # c and unclass -- preparing it for rle
  r <- rle(y)
  with(r, max(lengths[values==1]))
}
```

Now we can use it the usual dplyrry way:

```
df %>% group_by(key) %>% summarise(max.consecutive = gl(Date))

#  A tibble: 2 x 2
#     key max.consecutive
#   <int>           <int>
# 1     1               2
# 2     2               3
```

Comment: Hi @lebatsnok thanks for writing this, though I just had a quick question. When I count the max consecutive days in my sample table, I count 3 for key 1, and 4 for key 2. Does there need to be a `+ 1` somewhere in the function, and if so, is it because currently the function doesn't count either the start or end date?

Comment: right, you can  add 1 to the last row in the function. in addition, there should be sensible return value if none of the values returned by `rle` are 1 (i.e., if there are no consecutive dates). something like `if(any(r$values %in% 1)) with(r, max(lengths[values==1])) else 1` as the last row

Answer (score 0):

My solution: first split the dataset by key

```
df_split <- split(df, df$key)
```

then loop over the list and find the maximum length of the difference between consecutive days.

```
df_split <- split(df, df$key)

x <- lapply(df_split, 
            function(x){
               max(rle(diff(x$Date) == 1)$lengths[rle(diff(x$Date) == 1)$value != FALSE]+1)
            }
     )
```

Comment: This will give a wrong result if there are many non-consecutive dates in a row. Say, `d <- as.Date(c("2017-06-11", "2017-05-12", "2052-04-13", "2017-07-07"))` -- `diff(d)==1` will be FALSE 3 times, so `rle(diff(d)==1)$lengths` will be `3`. Which will, wrongly, pop out as the answer.