# By using R to find how many members filled the survey data continously --R

Tags: r

I am having survey data where the employee has to enter his data for following questions daily either in true/ False/ N/A for 5 days
I am trying to check if they have filled the data continously or not by using R

The data is as follows

```
EmployeeID <- c(101,101,101,102,102,102,102,104,104)
Created <- c(2020-06-19,2020-06-20,2020-06-21,2020-06-24,2020-06-25,2020-06-28,2020-06-28,2020-06-23,2020-06-24)
Updated <- c(2020-06-19,2020-06-20,2020-06-21,2020-06-24,2020-06-25,2020-06-28,2020-06-28,2020-06-23,2020-06-24)
happy <- c("True", "false", "false"," ", "false", "True","false", "True", "false")
active <- c("false", "false", " "," ", "false", "True"," ", "false", "false")
sad <- c("True", "false", "false"," ", "false", "True","false", "True", "false")
energitic <- c("True", "false", "false"," ", "false", "True","false", "True", "false")
df <- data.frame(EmployeeID, Created, Updated, happy, active, sad, energitic)
```

Comment: Could you please use `dput(data)`? This produces an output that you can copy into your question. That output allows anyone to quickly copy your data into R. Neither way you presented it (image or text dump) make that easy.

Comment: Hi I have update my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you may want to do is clean your data. First, your dates need to be in quotation marks, or R will treat them as subtractions.

```
Created <- c("2020-06-19","2020-06-20","2020-06-21","2020-06-24","2020-06-25",
             "2020-06-28","2020-06-28","2020-06-23","2020-06-24")
Updated <- c("2020-06-19","2020-06-20","2020-06-21","2020-06-24","2020-06-25",
             "2020-06-28","2020-06-28","2020-06-23","2020-06-24")
```

Now, when you build your data.frame, you get your dates looking correct. You can tell R they are dates, which is going to be needed for the analysis you want.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df <- df %>%
  mutate(across(ends_with("ed"), ymd))
head(df)
  EmployeeID    Created    Updated happy active   sad energitic
1        101 2020-06-19 2020-06-19  True  false  True      True
2        101 2020-06-20 2020-06-20 false  false false     false
3        101 2020-06-21 2020-06-21 false        false     false
4        102 2020-06-24 2020-06-24                             
5        102 2020-06-25 2020-06-25 false  false false     false
6        102 2020-06-28 2020-06-28  True   True  True      True
```

Second, you can tell R that your true/false values are logicals and not characters. This has bonus of converting your empty values to the `NA` values you said you had. This step is not necessary for what you want, but it may help you some later.

```
df <- df %>%
  mutate(across(where(is.character), as.logical))
head(df)
  EmployeeID    Created    Updated happy active   sad energitic
1        101 2020-06-19 2020-06-19  TRUE  FALSE  TRUE      TRUE
2        101 2020-06-20 2020-06-20 FALSE  FALSE FALSE     FALSE
3        101 2020-06-21 2020-06-21 FALSE     NA FALSE     FALSE
4        102 2020-06-24 2020-06-24    NA     NA    NA        NA
5        102 2020-06-25 2020-06-25 FALSE  FALSE FALSE     FALSE
6        102 2020-06-28 2020-06-28  TRUE   TRUE  TRUE      TRUE
```

Now, I understand that you want to know if a user completed the survey on consecutive days or if they skipped days. There may be a better way, but what we have below is an `anti_join` approach comparing the actual dates by employee versus the min/max range.

```
skipped_days <- df %>%
  group_by(EmployeeID) %>%
  summarise(date = seq(min(Created), max(Created), by = 1)) %>%
  anti_join(df, by = c("EmployeeID", "date" = "Created"))
skipped_days
# A tibble: 2 x 2
# Groups:   EmployeeID [1]
  EmployeeID date      
       <dbl> <date>    
1        102 2020-06-26
2        102 2020-06-27
```

Answer (score 1):

I thought @ben-norris gave a very complete answer and I upvoted it.  Especially the parts about bad starting data.  I did find a nice function that wraps around `rle` and gives us a chance to not only check for consecutive but canonically answer whether it was at least 5 in a row.  I generated some additional fake data to test with.

```r
# found at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53712962/r-count-maximum-number-of-consecutive-dates

gl <- function(x) {
   y <- c(unclass(diff(x)))  # c and unclass -- preparing it for rle
   r <- rle(y)
   with(r, max(lengths[values==1]))
}

library(dplyr)

df %>% 
   group_by(EmployeeID) %>% 
   summarise(max.consecutive = gl(Created) + 1)

#> `summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)
#> # A tibble: 4 x 2
#>   EmployeeID max.consecutive
#>        <dbl>           <dbl>
#> 1        101               3
#> 2        102               4
#> 3        103               6
#> 4        104               2
```

New fake data I didn't worry about columns that weren't germane to the question

```r
df <- structure(list(EmployeeID = c(101, 101, 101, 102, 102, 102, 102, 
                                    102, 104, 104, 103, 103, 103, 103, 103, 103, 103), Created = structure(c(18432, 
                                                                                                             18433, 18434, 18437, 18438, 18439, 18440, 18442, 18436, 18437, 
                                                                                                             18444, 18445, 18446, 18447, 18448, 18449, 18452), class = "Date"), 
                     Updated = structure(c(18432, 18433, 18434, 18437, 18438, 
                                           18441, 18441, 18436, 18440, 18437, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                                           NA), class = "Date"), happy = c("True", "false", "false", 
                                                                           " ", "false", "True", "false", "True", "false", "bogus", 
                                                                           NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), active = c("false", "false", 
                                                                                                                   " ", " ", "false", "True", " ", "false", "false", "bogus", 
                                                                                                                   NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), sad = c("True", "false", "false", 
                                                                                                                                                        " ", "false", "True", "false", "True", "false", "bogus", 
                                                                                                                                                        NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), energitic = c("True", "false", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                   "false", " ", "false", "True", "false", "True", "false", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                   "bogus", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        -17L), class = "data.frame")
```