# Trying to identify number of continuous purchases by ID using R

Tags: r

I have a data set

```
customerId <- c(101,101,101,102,102,102,104,104,106,109,109,109) 

Purchasedate<- c("2020-06-19","2020-06-20","2020-06-21","2020-06-24","2020-06-27","2020-06-28","2020-06-20","2020-06-21"
                 ,"2020-06-24","2020-06-10","2020-06-14","2020-06-16")
                 
df <- data.frame(customerId,Purchasedate)
```

I am trying to find out following output

```
101   3
104   2
```

as the `101` & `104` customer id only representing continuous purchase dates

I am trying to find out the customerid who had make continuous purchase and for how many days  by using R

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could consider checking for difference between dates using `group_by` for each id, `filter` by those ids where the difference is always 1, and `summarise` to total up the number of rows/dates:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(customerId) %>%
  mutate(diffDays = c(1, diff(Purchasedate))) %>%
  filter(n_distinct(diffDays) == 1 & n() > 1) %>%
  summarise(continuousDays = n())
```

**Output**

```
  customerId continuousDays
       <dbl>          <int>
1        101              3
2        104              2
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(customerId = c(101, 101, 101, 102, 102, 102, 104, 
104, 106, 109, 109, 109), Purchasedate = structure(c(18432, 18433, 
18434, 18437, 18440, 18441, 18433, 18434, 18437, 18423, 18427, 
18429), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `diff`.
x non-numeric argument to binary operator
i Input `diff` is `c(1, diff(Purchasedate))`.
i The error occurred in group 1: customerId = 101

Comment: Make sure your `Purchasedate` is a `date`: `df$Purchasedate <- as.Date(df$Purchasedate)
`

Answer (score 0):

A similar question was answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53713204/12400385

Adapting it slightly to your case

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

# Convert Purchasedate to a date column
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(Purchasedate = ymd(Purchasedate))

# Create custom function
max_consec <- function(x) {
  y <- c(unclass(diff(x)))  # c and unclass -- preparing it for rle
  r <- rle(y)
  with(r, max(lengths[values==1]) + 1)
}

# Apply function to each customer
df %>% 
  group_by(customerId) %>% 
  summarize(max.consecutive = max_consec(Purchasedate))


#-------
# A tibble: 5 x 2
  customerId max.consecutive
       <dbl>           <dbl>
1        101               3
2        102               2
3        104               2
4        106            -Inf
5        109            -Inf
```